# How to pass two arguments to a python function that is being called by ajax function?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am making a web app with Flask and want this function to be called when a button is clicked and the page not to reload:

```
@app.route('/add_song_to_playlist')
def add_song_to_playlist(pl_id, s_id):
    sp = songs_playlists(song_id = s_id, playlist_id = pl_id)
    db.session.add(sp)
    db.session.commit()
    return "nothing"
```

However it takes two arguments and I am not sure how to pass them in the ajax function. Also I need them to be like inline python code with {{ }}.

Here is the ajax function in the template and the button and what I tried to pass as the 'data' argument that getJSON() takes:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right float-left">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ url_for('make_playlist') }}"> Create a new playlist </a>
    {% for p in pl %}
    <form>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" id=add_song> {{ p.playlist_name }} </a>
    </form>
    <script type=text/javascript>
        $(function() {
            $('a#add_song').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            $.getJSON('/add_song_to_playlist', );
            return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But does not seem to work and I did not even expect it to work. I read the jquery documentation about this function but it said nothing about passing two arguments moreover as a python code (might be because of my lack of knowledge in JS). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can pass arguments either in the URL, as query parameters or in the body. There are many different formats to pass arguments in the body. Flask passes URL segments to the function call, e.g. `@app.route('/add_song_to_playlist/<pl_id>/<s_id>')`

Answer (score 0):

you can specify route params like this:

```
@app.route('/add_song_to_playlist/<pl_id>/<s_id>', methods=['POST'])
def add_song_to_playlist(pl_id, s_id):
    sp = songs_playlists(song_id = s_id, playlist_id = pl_id)
    db.session.add(sp)
    db.session.commit()
    return "nothing"
```

your http call should look something like this: *https://server_ip/add_song_to_playlist/playlist_id/song_id*

take a look here: https://pythonbasics.org/flask-tutorial-routes/

Or you can pass them through the body of a post call and then access them as follows:

```
@app.route('/add_song_to_playlist', methods=['POST'])
def add_song_to_playlist():
    pl_id = request.form.get('pl_id')
    s_id = request.form.get('s_id')
    sp = songs_playlists(song_id = s_id, playlist_id = pl_id)
    db.session.add(sp)
    db.session.commit()
    return "nothing"
```

Alternatively, also via get request: *https://server_ip/add_song_to_playlist?playlist_id=pl_id&song_id=s_id*

```
@app.route('/add_song_to_playlist', methods=['GET'])
def add_song_to_playlist():
    pl_id = request.args.get('pl_id')
    s_id = request.args.get('s_id')
    sp = songs_playlists(song_id = s_id, playlist_id = pl_id)
    db.session.add(sp)
    db.session.commit()
    return "nothing"
```

In my opinion the best way to manage the call in question is the first one.

Comment: Yes and now I need to pass the necessary arguments for the function. 
The arguments I need are from 2 lists which I get from the back-end when I render this template. So idk how it is done but I need something like this : $.getJSON('/add_song_to_playlist', {{ song.name }}, {{ p.playlist_name }})
IDK if I explain it well.

Comment: Sorry I accidentally uploaded the comment when it was not finished. Now it is edited.

Comment: If you can get playlist id and song id look here (how to make hhtp request with ajax): https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: I either cannot understand you because my lack of knowledge or you I cannot explain what I try to do. I have the template which I have passes two lists which are all the queries from two tables - songs and playlists so I can use them to display the songs and the playlists which is done by iterating these lists like that in the .html file: `{% for song in songs %} ... {% endfor %}`. Then I have a button which I want to call a function onclick without page reload which accepts elements from the two lists as args. And I dont know how to pass the 2 args when I call the function in the AJAX func

Comment: If you need to know ho to retrieve your playlist id and song id after button press from your html page take a look at this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I2dJuNwlIH0